# Shouldn't this site have an open question about the meaning of "the pot calling the kettle black"?

Tags: discussion

I think so—and it just so happens that we have a candidate that was asked in September 2013: [The meaning of the American idiom "pot calling the kettle black"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/127144/the-meaning-of-the-american-idiom-pot-calling-the-kettle-black). Unfortunately, because the question originally asked for survey-type responses (although none of the answers it drew attempted to respond to the survey aspects of the question), it was closed in December 2014. Even so, the question has attracted 11,763 unique viewers, so there is evidently substantial interest in the question. (Admittedly the poster erroneously describes the expression as "American.")

One of the working assumptions of close voting at this site is that if a question is fundamentally worthwhile but happens to be asked in a way that is sufficiently flawed to justify closure, some question asker will eventually come along and ask it in an acceptable way. But in the present case, the edited question no longer suffers from the fault that the closer cited in closing it.

In fact, the objectionable survey features of the question vanished more than a year ago, through subsequent editing of the question, and the question (as I write this) has received three reopen votes (again). I hope that site participants who have question-reopening privileges will consider voting to reopen this one.

EL&U does have one related open question: ["Pot calling the kettle black" ... but what if the kettle isn't black (figuratively speaking)?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/45205/pot-calling-the-kettle-black-but-what-if-the-kettle-isnt-black-figurativ) That question has attracted 2,529 viewers since it was posted in September 2011—but it focuses on a different (and I think, much narrower) issue.

Thanks for considering this request.

Comment: The question is now open once more. Thanks to everyone who took time to consider my request to reopen it.